# Relation Many to Many 'Property [moedas] does not exist on this collection instance '

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I would like to get `moeda` (coin in portuguese) data from `user` object. 
 But I'm getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcQ0r.png) saying that the property moedas does not exist.
 I have already created all the requirements pivot table, models,controllers  and view.

My models:

**Moeda**

```
namespace leilao;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Moeda extends Model
{
   public function users(){
         return $this->belongsToMany('leilao\User','moeda_user');
   }
}
```

**User**

```
<?php

namespace leilao;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use leilao\Moeda;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function moedas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('leilao\Moeda','moeda_user');
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php

namespace leilao\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use leilao\User;
use leilao\Moeda;
class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
 $userCollection=User::with('moedas')->get();  
public function lista(){

    return view('lista')->with('users', $userCollection);
}

}
```

**My View**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<?php foreach ($users->moedas as $c): ?>
<tr>
   td><?= $c->currencia ?></td>
   <td><?= $c->valor ?></td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

**Pivot Table**

The migration up method was done as follow:

```
public function up()
{
      Schema::create('moeda_user', function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('moeda_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); //unsingned não permite valores negativos
  $table->foreign('moeda_id')->references('id')
        ->on('moedas')->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
        ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->timestamps();
});    }
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: You que see here [stack trace - screenshot version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vggzmiz93a1yob2/Snap%202018-02-05%20at%2001.27.58.png?dl=0) and here 

[stack trace - text file version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8wetjjxjo59897/stack%20trace.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you put a log statement in that `__get()` method of `Support/Collection`? See what type `static` is and what `static::$proxies` has in it?

Comment: Suddenly it started working ! 
I just iterated  using this expression `users-> as  u` and I got the data  like this `u->moedas->someColoumn` . I'm almost sure I had tried it before. I've been expending one week trying to solve this problem. And than suddenly for no reason it started working !!! Many thanks for you comprehension.

Comment: Oh you had a collection of users to iterate first then. That would make sense. At least it's working hah

Comment: I released that the error was caused because one register of the `user` table had no relation the other table. I got the error trying to access no existent property. But I can't understand why.  If I'm passing, from controller  to the view, a collection filtered with this expression `$userCollection = User::with('moedas')->get()` . As far as I'm understanding the view is supposed to have only registers that have no empty relation. Only `users` with `moeda` inside.

Answer (score 0):

You've got mismatched capitalization between your class name and the relationship's first parameter:

```
// uppercase leilao\Moeda
public function moedas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('leilao\Moeda','moeda_user');
}

// lowercase
class moeda extends Model
```

Comment: This typo I made while formatting the question. Is not present im my code.
Thanks any way for your answer

Comment: Easy to make, but it would have at least explained your error so I thought I should mention it.